# Remove warning alert subscription to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: alert

I need to know how to completely remove the warning mail subscription to an alert. I do not want this mail will come to those who subscribe. I just want mails arrive with the creation of the element and its modifications.
Thank you for your help.
Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

The way that first jumps to mind on this is to create custom alert templates that have a custom handler for the update.

If you read this classic solution from msdn:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx

You will see how to implement an IAlertHandler and use the NotificationHandlerAssembly in the template XML to point to it. My guess for how to accomplish what you are trying to do is to implement a custom handler for the UpdateHandlerAssembly. Here is an XML snippet for the CallTrack Alert Template in the XML file located at (12 or 14)\TEMPLATE\XML\alerttemplates.xml

```
    <Properties>
      <UpdateHandlerAssembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</UpdateHandlerAssembly> 
      <UpdateHandlerClassName>Microsoft.SharePoint.Applications.GroupBoard.CallTrackingAlertHandler</UpdateHandlerClassName> 
      <UpdateHandlerProperties /> 
    </Properties>
```

A quick google search gave me hope that you could make these changes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897791(v=office.12).aspx for example talks about methods that are called when updates are made to alerts. It may take some time to ferret out how to customize the emails that are sent when an alert is modified, but since you are just killing the notifications you could add a handler that takes no action to the template and then alerts would certainly not send emails. You may want to verify that email is the only action taken when alerts are modified because if you write a custom handler you will be on the hook to provide all the methods.

Unfortunately this is not an answer, this is more like me pointing to where I think the answer is.